# Send headers from Apollo Vue to Node

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo

I'm doing a little api with register and auth using jwt, apollo-vue and graphql

I can`t get data through queries (or set it through mutations) from/to my backend.
But i can do it from Postman, cause i know how to send a token in the headers.

I'm too try to call `onLogin(apolloClient, token)` bellow the action login from vuex. Nothings work

I'm very newby with backend, i will appreciate any advice

**Another problem?** : If in the function below...

```
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  // add here console.log(localStorage.getItem('apollo-token'))
  const token = await localStorage.getItem('apollo-token')
  // and then console.log(token)

  return {...}
})
```

The first console print a token, but the second console print `null`. This is weird for me.

This is my `vue-apollo.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import { createApolloClient, restartWebsockets } from 'vue-cli-plugin-apollo/graphql-client'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'

Vue.use(VueApollo)

const AUTH_TOKEN = 'apollo-token'

// Http endpoint
const httpEndpoint = process.env.VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_HTTP || 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  return {
    ...headers,
    Authorization: token || ''
  }
})

// Files URL root
export const filesRoot = process.env.VUE_APP_FILES_ROOT || httpEndpoint.substr(0, httpEndpoint.indexOf('/graphql'))

Vue.prototype.$filesRoot = filesRoot

// Config
const defaultOptions = {
  httpEndpoint,
  wsEndpoint: null,
  tokenName: AUTH_TOKEN,
  websocketsOnly: false,
  ssr: false,
  link: authLink
}

export const { apolloClient } = createApolloClient({
  ...defaultOptions,
})
 

export function createProvider(options = {}) {
  const { apolloClient, wsClient } = createApolloClient({
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...options,
  })
  apolloClient.wsClient = wsClient


  const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: apolloClient,
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        // fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      },
    },
    errorHandler(error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('%cError', 'background: red; color: white; padding: 2px 4px; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;', error.message)
    },
  })

  return { apolloProvider, apolloClient }
}

// Manually call this when user log in
export async function onLogin(apolloClient, token) {
  if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' && token) {
    localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token)
  }
  if (apolloClient.wsClient) restartWebsockets(apolloClient.wsClient)
  try {
    await apolloClient.resetStore()
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('%cError on cache reset (login)', 'color: orange;', e.message)
  }
}

// Manually call this when user log out
export async function onLogout(apolloClient) {
  if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  }
  if (apolloClient.wsClient) restartWebsockets(apolloClient.wsClient)
  try {
    await apolloClient.resetStore()
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('%cError on cache reset (logout)', 'color: orange;', e.message)
  }
}
```

main.js from vue

```
// HTTP connection to the API
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  // You should use an absolute URL here
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
})
// Cache implementation
const cache = new InMemoryCache()

// Create the apollo client
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache,
})


Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueScreen)
  .use(VueApollo)

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
})


new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  apolloProvider,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

> **EDIT:** more code

This is the query, in a view on vue

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  apollo: {
    Users: gql`
      {
        Users {
          _id
          username
          email
          password
          token
          createdAt
        }
      },
    `,   
  },
};
```

The error that i receive is:

> bundle.esm.js:75 POST http://localhost:3000/graphql 500 (Internal Server Error)

> Error sending the query 'Users' ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 500
> at throwServerError

In the backend, this is my query

```
Query: {
    async Users(_, req, context) {
        const auth = checkAuth(context)
        if (auth.id) {
            const users = await User.find()
            users.forEach(e => {
                e.password = null
            })
            return users
        } else {
            return new Error("must be logged.")
        }
    },
```

and this is my checkAuth.js

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { AuthenticationError } from 'apollo-server'
import 'dotenv/config'


module.exports = (context) => {
    const authHeader = context.headers.authorization;
    console.log("headers: ",context.headers)
    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split('Bearer ')[1];
        if (token) {
            try {
                const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
                return user
            } catch (err) {
                return new AuthenticationError("Invalid token.")
            }
        }
        return new Error("Token must be 'Bearer [token]'")
    }
    return new Error("I need a token bro!")
}
```

> **EDIT 2**

the context.header received on the backend

```
headers: {
    host: 'localhost:3000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '160',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
    accept: '*/*',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    origin: 'http://localhost:8081',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    referer: 'http://localhost:8081/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'es-419,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
  },
```

Comment: Can you be more clear when you "say nothing works". If you take look at the console. what error is printed when you execute the query ?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. The error occurs only from the frontend. The same query in Postman, but with the token in headers, works fine. The error and more code, is now added below the question.

Comment: @Joyescat maybe there's some way to send the header in the Apollo object, from the frontend's query?

Comment: What error is printed in the backend logs ? Is "Invalid token.", "Token must be 'Bearer [token]'", or "I need a token bro!" error is triggered ?

Comment: What do you mean by "there's some way to send the header in the Apollo object, from the frontend's query?". You're already sending the header with the token in the `setContext` function in `vue-apollo.js`

Comment: this is what i believed, but if i put a ``console.log`` bellow ``async Users(_, req, context) { `` ,  in my backend query, shouldn't get the headers with the token in node console? i don't see it

Comment: You don't see the headers in the console.log or you don't see anything from the consol.log at all ?

Comment: i recevie a context.header with host (localhost:3000), connection, accept, origin, and referer props. Don't have 'authorization'

Comment: if i put a console.log() in the authlink function (in ``vue-apollo.js``), all the data is empty (token & headers). It is as if it were executed before any other action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vue-apollo.js` file is not used.

In your `main.js` the `apolloClient` you inject in Vue is declared in the `main.js` and doesn't contain the `authLink`. **All your code in** `vue-apollo.js` **isn't called**.

So instead of this:

```js
// HTTP connection to the API
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  // You should use an absolute URL here
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
})
// Cache implementation
const cache = new InMemoryCache()

// Create the apollo client
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache,
})


Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueScreen)
  .use(VueApollo)

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
})


new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  apolloProvider,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Try this:

```js
import { createProvider } from 'vue-apollo.js';

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueScreen)
  .use(VueApollo)

const { apolloProvider, apolloClient } = createProvider();

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  apolloProvider,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: oh man, thanks a lot. you saved my day, Messi bless you

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, you only send the token in the authorization header.

```js
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  return {
    ...headers,
    Authorization: token || ''
  }
})
```

but in the backend you expect to find a bearer token:

```js
module.exports = (context) => {
    const authHeader = context.headers.authorization;
    console.log("headers: ",context.headers)
    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split('Bearer ')[1]; << Your code is breaking here
        if (token) {
            try {
                const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
                return user
            } catch (err) {
                return new AuthenticationError("Invalid token.")
            }
        }
        return new Error("Token must be 'Bearer [token]'")
    }
    return new Error("I need a token bro!")
}
```

You must send 'Bearer [token]' instead of just the token. Like so:

```js
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  return {
    ...headers,
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-context) this is how `setContext` is used:

```js
const setAuthorizationLink = setContext((request, previousContext) => ({
  headers: {authorization: "1234"}
}));
```

> The setContext function takes a function that returns either an object or a promise that returns an object to set the new context of a request.

In the code below you only return the headers. When you're supposed to return the context.

```js
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  return {
    ...headers,
    Authorization: token || ''
  }
})
```

Try this instead

```js
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token || ''
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: it didn't work too. the context.header that i receive in checkAuth.js doesn't have the authorization key.